# Count frequency of each element in a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm triying to achieve the behavior of `collections.Counter()` but with a list of dictionnaries.

Giving a list of dicts : `[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 0, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}]`

The function should return :
`{"a": 1, "b": 2} : 2`
`{"a": 0, "b": 2} : 1`

Comment: what's your expected output type?

Comment: I want to be able to `print()` the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is not hashable, this means that applying directly a Counter would not work.
However, you could use the Counter with a list of frozensets obtained from your input list.

```
>>> Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in l)
Counter({frozenset({('b', 2), ('a', 1)}): 2, frozenset({('a', 0), ('b', 2)}): 1})
```